# AJAX GET request successful; Django View updated but HTML does not get updated

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, django

This has completely stumped me and I have stared at the screen for a long time now.
It is about a mail app that I am trying to develop. I have an HTML page that is divided in three parts. Left side has the ability to check/uncheck folders from which to view emails. Middle page "should" show all the mails (depending upon what is selected on the left column). The right most column is expanded view of individual mail in the middle. 
I added AJAX GET request feature to pass to view which folders have been selected or unselected. The view gets the AJAX request all right (in the code below I print out args and it is right what I want it to be). However the HTML page/template never responds to the changing args!! I don't know why? Please help me locate the bug in my program.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name="Home"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.Home_View.as_view(),name="Home"),
    url(r'^RightBody/$', views.RightBody, name="RightBody"),
    url(r'^RulePopUp/$', views.RulePopUp_View.as_view(), name="RulePopUp"),
    ]
```

views.py

```
class Home_View(View):

    def get(self, request):
        ExcludedFolder = request.GET.getlist('UncheckedFolder[]')
        LeftSide_FolderHandle = FolderTree("/SomePath/")
        LeftSide_Folder = LeftSide_FolderHandle.CreateFolderNames()
        LeftSide_Folder = LeftSide_FolderHandle.MakeAJSONtree()
        CompleteMailBox_Handle = MailLogger("/SomePath/",FoldersToExclude=ExcludedFolder)
        CompleteMailBox = CompleteMailBox_Handle.RecreateMailBox()
        # RightMail = FullMailInTheRight()
        args = {"CompleteMailBox":CompleteMailBox,
                "LeftSide_FolderStructure":LeftSide_Folder}
        print(args) ##This works
        return render(request,'Home_Query.html',args)
```

Home_Query.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.2.1.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/HomePageMain.css' %}" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="Headline"> Mail checking app </h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="left-column">
      Select folders to display messages
      <br>
      <br>
{% include "Home_Query_LeftSide.html" with LeftSide_FolderStructure=LeftSide_FolderStructure %}
    </div>
    <div class="middle-column">
      Select Message to show complete mail on the right
      <br>
      <br>
      {% for eachMail in CompleteMailBox %}
        <div class="SingleMail">
            <span class="EachMailSender"> Sender: </span> <span class="MailSender">{{eachMail.0.Sender}}</span>, <span class="EachMailTime">Time: </span> <span class="MailTime">{{eachMail.0.Time}}</span> <br>
            <span class="EachMailSubject">Subject: </span> <span class="Subject">{{eachMail.0.Subject}}</span><br>
            <span class="EachMailBody"> Mail: </span>{{eachMail.1}}
            <div class="Rules">
              <p id="Rules">Click here for rules</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      This column shows the complete email when selected in the middle column
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="FullMail">
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var Unchecked = [];

$(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',$(this).is(':checked'));
      if ($(".left-column").find("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").length != 0){
        var UncheckedFolder = "";
        $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(){
          UncheckedFolder += "/"+String($(this).prop("id"));
        });
        if ($.inArray(UncheckedFolder, Unchecked) === -1) {Unchecked.push(UncheckedFolder)}
        var CheckedFolder = "";
        $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
          CheckedFolder += "/"+String($(this).prop("id"));
        });
        if ($.inArray(CheckedFolder, Unchecked) != -1) {Unchecked.splice($.inArray(CheckedFolder,Unchecked),1);}
        UncheckedFolder = "";
      }
      else {
        Unchecked = [];
      }
      console.log(Unchecked);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "/Home/",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {
          'UncheckedFolder':Unchecked,
        },
        success: PrintMessage,
      });
    });
});

function PrintMessage(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
  console.log("Success To Exclude");
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Return a `JsonResponse` instead of `render:`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class Home_View(View):

    def get(self, request):
        ...
        print(args) ##This works
        return JsonResponse(args)
```

The javascript call is expecting a response in json format. With `render` you are returning an HTML template.

Comment: Thank you. I worked on your suggestion and changed the response from render to JsonResponse and manually recreated the page in the Ajax success call (the same page that would have been rendered by Django's render method). However I kept wondering why render did not work. I guess the answer is in hooks/middleware. Once a Ajax initiates a get call it waits for a Jsonresponse only and the results will be transferred to the Ajax only and that call has to complete. May be render tries to bypass this whole things which the middleware prevents..but all this is my guess ..I may be totally wrong.Thanks